# Update statement with TINYINT variables raises error in mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax, sql-update, tinyint

I try to get a simple update query to work in mySQL, and I can't find an answer.

What I try to do, for "agroforestry" is a tinyint variable :

```
UPDATE Projects
SET agroforestry = FALSE,
WHERE project_id=2;
```

This following query works perfectly on the same dataset :

```
UPDATE Projects
SET contact_person_mail='vincent@lao.be',
    geographical_scope='national',
    country='Belgium',
    budget=4500000,
    currency='EUR'
WHERE project_id=2;
```

... But I get a syntax error when I try to update tinyint (boolean) variables. I have tried all this :

```
agroforestry = FALSE
agroforestry = False
agroforestry = false
agroforestry = 'FALSE'
agroforestry = 'False'
agroforestry = 'false'
agroforestry = 0
agroforestry = 1
agroforestry = TRUE
...
```

Nothing works ! What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Remove the extra comma. Voting to close as a typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example, you have

```
UPDATE Projects
SET agroforestry = FALSE,
WHERE project_id=2;
```

Take the comma out, after FALSE.  It doesn't belong there.
Commas in a `SET` clause exist only in separating columns.  The last column (in this case, the only column) to be modified cannot be followed by a comma.

Comment: haha, thanks.  Hopefully that's the only issue, it sure is the only issue I can see.  Guess we'll see, if the asker accepts the answer.  :)